# how to use sprintf on multiline raw string using named placeholders after building the string?

Tags: c++, c++11

In Python or Perl or Ruby, one can build a multiline raw string (called HERE-DOCUEMNT sometimes) and then, after the string is build, replace some parts of the string (tokens using `%s`) inside the string, using named parameters. Similar to use `sprintf` on a string, except using names to help point to these locations inside the raw string.

This is very useful. I can only do part of the above in C++, but do not know if it is possible to do the string replacement using named place holders.

I'll show very simple example in Python, then show my attempt to do the same in C++

```
s=r"""
\begin{document}
\title{%(title)s}

This was written on %(date)s

And also updated on %(date)s and so on"""

print s % {"title": "main report","date": "1/1/2015"}
```

The above prints

```
\begin{document}
\title{main report}

This was written on 1/1/2015

And also updated on 1/1/2015 and so on
```

In C++, the best I could do is this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
#include <cstdio>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
        char buffer [500];
        string s =

R"(
\begin{document}
\title{%s}

This was written on %s

And also updated on %s and so on
)";    
        snprintf(buffer,500,s.c_str(),"main report","1/1/2015","1/1/2015");
        cout<<buffer<<endl;
        return 0;
}
```

And now

```
>g++ -Wall -std=c++0x ./t1.cpp
>./a.out

\begin{document}
\title{main report}

This was written on 1/1/2015

And also updated on 1/1/2015 and so on
```

There are 2 problems: How to best do the `sprintf` without having to manually allocate buffer with correct size, to be able to hold the new string (after the replacement)?

Second problem, is it possible to do named replacement as in the example in Python? This way, if there are many place holders in the raw string, and some might be repeated in different locations, as with `date` in the above example, they all can be replaced at once.

Comment: for a start, get rid of `cstr`, and use `s.c_str()` as 3rd argument to `snprintf`

Comment: @MattMcNabb I did this before, but I get an error. I am using g++ V4.8 on linux.
`>g++ -Wall -std=c++0x ./t1.cpp
./t1.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
./t1.cpp:22:72: error: cannot convert ‘std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>::c_str<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >’ from type ‘const char* (std::basic_string<char>::)()const noexcept (true)’ to type ‘const char*’
         snprintf(buffer,500,s.c_str,"main report","1/1/2015","1/1/2015");`

Comment: You need `#include <string>`.  If that still doesnt help, try taking out `R` and using `\n` instead of hard line breaks. Raw literals are new and g++ might be buggy. It works for me in g++ 4.9 tho.

Comment: @MattMcNabb Thanks, include string.h worked. WIll update.

Comment: `string` and `string.h` are different

Answer (score 1):

Q2: Not named replacement, but put the duplicated item into a variable and use that variable when required.

Q1: C++ doesn't have a built-in format-string formatter for `std::string`. You could install an addon such as Boost or Poco to get one of those.  But there's nothing wrong with using `snprintf` like you did.

An alternative approach is to build the string without formatting:

```
string title = "main report";
string date = "1-01-2015";
string s = "(\n\\begin{document}\n\\title{" + arg + "}\n\n"
    "This was written on " + date + "\n\n"
    "And also updated on " + date + " and so on\n)";
```

If you wanted to stick with `snprintf`, it is possible to call it to determine the buffer size: `snprintf(NULL, 0, formatstring, args......);` will return the number of bytes that would be printed (so allocate 1 more than that).  I wouldn't bother in your case, 500 is plenty and if you are really worried you can check the return value of `snprintf` and trigger an error if it exceeded 500.

Answer (score 1):

There's a [C++ library from facebook](https://github.com/facebook/folly/blob/master/folly/docs/Format.md) that lets you do some bits of named printf like formatting:

```
std::map<std::string, std::string> m { {"what", "answer"}, {"value", "42"} };
std::cout << vformat("The only {what} is {value}", m);
```

Output `The only answer is 42`